# how can I see if I have the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to suspend my PC (Windows 10 Pro) for a certain time using the Task Scheduler. In practice, I run a batch file that has a certain time that suspends the PC. Next I have to run another batch file that will turn it on.

My problem is that these commands do not work:

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

and not by any error. I checked the Event Log Explorer and it shows me only EventID 187 (ApiCallerNameLength) without activating EventID 42 (which should activate the suspension of windows).

I tried various ways to solve the problem, but I failed to understand why it didn't work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate

In my opinion, this article is a privilege problem. Can you help me?

Comment: This question is better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: check by *whoami /priv*

Answer (score 0):

You can check your privileges by using `whoami /priv` and you should see something like:

```
Privilege Name                            Description                                                        State
========================================= ================================================================== ========
SeShutdownPrivilege                       Shut down the system                                               Disabled
```

If the privilege is listed, that means your user account has the privilege. It must be specifically **enabled** during the script in order to be used:

> To shut down the local computer, the calling **thread** must have the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege. By default, **users can enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME** privilege on the computer they are logged onto, and administrators can enable the SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on remote computers.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/1254253/how-am-i-able-to-shutdown-the-system-when-i-dont-have-seshutdownprivilege)

I have not found a plain batch solution to enable this privilege, but you can accomplish the same thing by using SysInternals' [`psshutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) tool with the `-d` option.

The PowerShell solutions for this that I found to modify privileges during script execution didn't work for me.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, I have proved "psshutdown -d" but it gaves me this error: PsShutdown v2.52 - Shutdown, logoff and power manage local and remote systems
Copyright (C) 1999-2006 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't install PsShutdown service:
Accesso negato.

If The local system is already performing a shutdown operation you must
abort it before issuing a different command. Then I think to use [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) to enable the privilege